Is there a maximum number of disjoint balls of fixed radius I can fit into a compact metric space?
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and fix $r>0$. By sequential compactness, one may not find an infinite number of disjoint $r$-balls (sets $B_r(x):=\{y \in X: d(x,y)<r\}$) in $X$ as this gives rise to a sequence with no convergent subsequence.
However, does this mean that there is a maximum number of disjoint $r$-balls $X$ can contain? What precludes one from finding a collection of $n$ disjoint $r$-balls for each large $n$?
I realise that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the answer is affirmative by a measure-theoretic argument, but for general compact metric spaces I am not sure.

Yes, there is such a maximum. You can first prove the following well-known fact.

A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

The key is that compact metric spaces are totally bounded, which means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that there is some covering of $X$ by $N$ $\varepsilon$-balls.
So, given compact metric space $X$ and $r > 0$, there exists a covering of $X$ by some collection of $N$ $\frac{1}{2} r$-balls. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that we have a collection $\{B_d (m_1, r), \cdots, B_d (m_M, r)\}$ of $M$ disjoint balls of radius $r$, where $M > N$. By the pigeonhole principle, there must exist two centers $m_i \ne m_j$ that belong to the same ball in the cover. Then $d (m_i, m_j) < r$, which contradicts the fact that $B_d (m_i, r), B_d (m_j, r)$ are disjoint (e.g., we have that $m_i \in B_d (m_i, r) \cap B_d (m_j, r)$).

The answer is affirmative: for take a finite covering of the space with subsets of diameter $< 2 r$
Packing number vs. covering number...
